# Checking if text includes any of the words from a vocabulary?

Tags: string, python-3.x

If given an iterable of words (hundreds of thousands of them) is there an efficient existing library for checking whether any of the words in the iterable are contained in a string?

I can easily make a very long regex pattern that or's together all the words and then tries to match that regex against my string. Was mainly wondering if there's something cleaner out there that I could use, since then I don't need to worry about escaping any possible special characters appearing in the words.

In other words, something along the lines of:

```
words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
finder = WordFinder(words)
finder.find('sdfs s dfs df sdfsdfsdfoo sdf sdf') # True
finder.find('sdfasdfasdfa barasdfs') # True
finder.find('sdfsadsfs f sd fsa f df asdf sd fs') # False
```

I already wrote a class like this myself based of regexes, so was hoping I can delete that code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Aho-Corasick will fit your requirements?

Here's it's wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

And a Python module implementing it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick